# NotificationCompat.Builder setContentText() does not show CSS colour in dark mode

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am displaying text on the second line of my notification using `builder.setContentText(txt)`, where the `txt` is actually styled text based on html including CSS colours, to produce coloured text.

The code I'm using is:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId);
// ... various stuff ... then ...
String decodedHeader = Uri.decode(header);
Log.d(TAG, "decodedHeader: " + decodedHeader);
Spanned styledText = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(decodedHeader, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
builder.setContentText(styledText);
Notification notification = builder.build();
```

and the log output (to show the html/css content) is:

```
decodedHeader: <span style="color:#333333;">↓72%</span><span style="color:#333333;"> │ </span><span style="color:#0ca911;">5°C</span><span style="color:#333333;"> │ </span><span style="color:#ff3333;">2°C↓</span><span style="color:#333333;"> │ </span><span style="color:#ff80c1;">4°C</span><span style="color:#333333;"> │ </span><span style="color:#00764a;">92%</span><span style="color:#333333;"> │ </span><span style="color:#5546ff;">14 mm</span><span style="color:#333333;"> │ </span><span style="color:#fd93fd;">8 (17) mph</span><span style="color:#333333;"> │ </span><span style="color:#333333;">19:34</span>
```

When the system (running Android 10) is in light mode, the notification shows these colours just fine:

[image]

but when the system is in dark mode, the colours are lost:

[image]

is this just something enforced by the system, over which I have no control?

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme) they clearly said

> **Themes and styles**
>  Your themes and styles should avoid hard-coded colors or icons intended for use under a light theme. You
>   should use theme attributes (preferred) or night-qualified resources
>   instead.

And also to specific for Notifications.

Common pitfalls to look out for:

- Assuming that the background color is always light
- Hardcoding text colors
- Setting a hardcoded background color, while using the default text
  color
- Using a drawable icon which is a static color

In all of these cases, use appropriate theme attributes instead of hardcoded colors.

Comment: These aren't really hardcoded colours.  They are CSS colours that are user defined (from somewhere else... long story).  The intention is to allow the user to set the colour of each component of the second line of the notification.  What I don't understand (and this is the reason for the question) is why the method works when in light mode but not dark mode... surely it should either work (or not) for both?